# Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I am trying to run the sample Android app of the Google Calendar API. Eclipse tells me that the SDK emulator is not compatible with my code, while it is happy with my real device running the same version of Android. I am probably missing something obvious here, but just cannot figure out what.

Thanks in advance for helping

[image]

Comment: I think you probably need to make sure you are using the Google API's version of the emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious thing that you are missing is that you need the `Google APIs 2.3.3` version, not the `Android 2.3.3` version as the later does not contain *Google* components such as the *Google Calendar API*.

Comment: Yep. In AVD Manager it's listed as `Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 10` when selecting `Target` for the emulator.